# Left join only selected columns in R with the merge() function

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to LEFT Join 2 data frames but I do not want join all the variables from the second data set:

As an example, I have dataset 1 (DF1):

```
  Cl    Q   Sales  Date
   A    2   30     01/01/2014
   A    3   24     02/01/2014
   A    1   10     03/01/2014
   B    4   10     01/01/2014
   B    1   20     02/01/2014
   B    3   30     03/01/2014
```

And I would like to left join dataset 2 (DF2):

```
Client  LO  CON
   A    12  CA
   B    11  US
   C    12  UK
   D    10  CA
   E    15  AUS
   F    91  DD
```

I am able to left join with the following code:

merge(x = DF1, y = DF2, by = "Client", all.x=TRUE) :

```
   Client Q    Sales   Date             LO      CON
   A      2    30      01/01/2014       12      CA
   A      3    24      02/01/2014       12      CA
   A      1    10      03/01/2014       12      CA
   B      4    10      01/01/2014       11      US
   B      1    20      02/01/2014       11      US
   B      3    30      03/01/2014       11      US
```

However, it merges both column LO and CON. I would only like to merge the column LO.

```
   Client Q    Sales   Date             LO      
   A      2    30      01/01/2014       12      
   A      3    24      02/01/2014       12      
   A      1    10      03/01/2014       12      
   B      4    10      01/01/2014       11      
   B      1    20      02/01/2014       11     
   B      3    30      03/01/2014       11
```

Comment: you need to rename "Cl" into "Client" in DF1 (in the written example above). Otherwise the merge function does not work.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can do this by subsetting the data you pass into your merge:

```
merge(x = DF1, y = DF2[ , c("Client", "LO")], by = "Client", all.x=TRUE)
```

Or you can simply delete the column after your current merge :)

Comment: remembering that you need to include the variable you are merging by

Answer (score 29):

I think it's a little simpler to use the `dplyr` functions `select` and `left_join` ; at least it's easier for me to understand.  The join function from `dplyr` are made to mimic sql arguments.

```
 library(tidyverse)

 DF2 <- DF2 %>%
   select(client, LO)

 joined_data <- left_join(DF1, DF2, by = "Client")
```

You don't actually need to use the "by" argument in this case because the columns have the same name.

Comment: Is it `%<%` or `%>%`?

Comment: Yep, that was a typo. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing elegant but this could be another satisfactory answer.

```
merge(x = DF1, y = DF2, by = "Client", all.x=TRUE)[,c("Client","LO","CON")]
```

This will be useful especially when you don't need the keys that were used to join the tables in your results.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution using `left_join()` and `select()` from the `dplyr` package, without intermediate steps:

```
DF1 <- DF1 %>%
  left_join(DF2, by = "Client") %>%
  select(-CON)
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner with `dplyr`

```
DF_joined <- left_join(DF1, select(DF2, -CON), by = "Client")
```

Answer (score 1):

For *Client* column in both tables:

```
DF_joined <- DF1 %>% left_join(DF2 %>% select(Client,CON))
```