# Fix.by() error in R using merge()

Tags: r

The below R code generates following error. Same pattern seems to be working for people [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191497/left-join-only-selected-columns-in-r-with-the-merge-function), but not here. What could be cause?:

> Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

```
dd1 <- data.frame("a" = 1:4, "b" = c(21,22,23,24))
dd2 <- data.frame("a" = 1:4, "c" = 31:34, "d" = c(41,42,43,44), "e" = 51:54)

merge(x = dd1, y = dd2[,c("c","d")], by= "a", all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: You've subset your dd2 dataframe so that it no longer includes "a", you need to leave it in to match

Comment: `y = dd2[,c("c","d")]` it does not look like your second df has column `a` in it